# cvs update with ignore

Tags: cvs, ignore

I have a huge CVS repo which is frequently changing, but the changes a small. Lets say I have a huge amount of small file, but only the *.text files are changing, which are just a fraction of the files. I wish to ignore everything else during the update.

Currently my update takes about a minute, I believe it's because there are a tons of file to check. if the ignore would skip all of them, the update would be much faster.

Here is what I'm trying now:
[cvsignore](http://march-hare.com/library/cvsnt/cvsignore.html)

time cvs update -I *.gif

I committed some *.gif to the repo and on the other machine I'm doing the update, unfortunately, I'm getting the gif files.

Any idea?

Comment: Are the text files in a specific directory or spread out throughout the repository?

Comment: Spread. I wish to use at least a *.txt *.doc style filtering.

Answer (score 0):

cvsignore is not doing what you think it does.  cvsignore is only relevant for files which occur in your working copy, but you don't wish to put them under version control.

CVS is not designed for your requirement.  It is designed to work on complete directory trees. The goal is to achieve consistency between the repository and the working copy.

From my experience 'cvs update' will be the fastest if you put all files under version control.  You can also try and measure the duration of 'cvs update *.txt' followed by 'cvs update *.doc'.  If this is still not fast enough for your requirement, you might have to look into different tooling (e.g. rsync).